# How to get password from another table?

Tags: laravel

I'm implementing a login API using Laravel 5.4 for a company that already has two tables where they store username and password. I'm using Tymons `JWTAuth` which uses the default auth. How can I override the authentication so that it gets the password from another table and not the users table?

Currently I'm using my localhost and the default users table

```
public function login() {
    $credentials = $request->only('user', 'password');
    try {

    if ( ! $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials))
    {
        return response()->json([
            'error' => 'Your email or password is incorrect'
        ], 401);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#joins

Comment: I already know how to join tables. I'm asking how do I override the auth so that the password comes from another table and not the users table.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44727720/revisions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to create a view in my database from the two tables. Seemed like the easiest solution

Answer (score 0):

> already has two tables where they store username and password

The best way you can do is copy your data to the Auth tables. If you don't want to use the password from the auth, then better rewrite it from scratch and don't use Auth to make your life simplier. Goodluck!